# Computing Quantile of RFM values

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

I was trying to compute and derive Quantile of RFM values,

```
rfm['r_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rfm['recency'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'])
rfm['f_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rfm['frequency'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'])
rfm['m_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rfm['monetary'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'])
rfm.head()
```

I am getting this error,

```
ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1., 37.]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg
```

I tried including the duplicates='drop' argument, like this:

```
rfm['r_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rfm['recency'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'], duplicates='drop')
rfm['f_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rfm['frequency'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'],duplicates='drop')
rfm['m_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rfm['sum_non_compliance'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'],duplicates='drop')
```

Getting another error;

```
ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges
```

Not sure why I am getting this!

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: What happens if you don't pass `labels`?

Comment: tried deleting labels "['1','2','3','4']". but still getting same error